# Http current request from a non- web.page class

Tags: c#

Is there any way to access an http curent request in

- a bll project that is used by website project?
- a class which doesn't inherit from page?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with this

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

You'll need to reference `system.web` assembly (it may smell for some people)